# Can't load tun module in Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, linux-kernel

I am trying to set up a VPN connection, but OpenVPN fails with

```
ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)
```

`modprobe tun` has no effect, and `modinfo tun` shows that the module isn't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If it worked before, perhaps you have recently updated your kernel but haven't done a reboot – that would explain why `modprobe tun` fails. Check your running kernel version:

```
uname -a
```

and your latest *installed* kernel version (you can use `pacman -Q linux` on Arch or look into `/lib/modules/` on most systems). If they don't match, reboot – the latest kernel will be loaded and `tun` module with it.